# People Reached - meaning

Tags: support

First, I apologize for coming here. I spent two hours this evening in tour and help and got nowhere, and I do not otherwise know where to go in SU / Stack Exchange for help.

My question is simple. What is People Reached? What does it mean? How is it calculated. Why should I care?

Thank you for any assistance you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 5):

#### What is People Reached?

It is **not** Profile Views, as you might imagine Profile views is the number of people that have visited your profile page.

> People Reached is the approximate number of people that your posts have been seen by. (Although that's a very loose interpretation. There is more info on that here: "[We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)").

Source [Difference between Profile Views and People reached - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269605/difference-between-profile-views-and-people-reached)

#### How is it calculated?

> Ultimately we reduced our criteria to:
>
> > Views of pages where your helpful posts had some decent probability of being seen.
>
> That doesn't mean we know the visitor scrolled to your post, or that
>   your answer helped them - we simply don't track that. But we should be
>   able to estimate the likelihood of a given question or answer been
>   seen as useful by viewers without enabling the 25th answer on an
>   insanely popular post to get a lucky up-vote and credit all the views
>   to the new author.
>
> That's how we got to the current method, which counts views on the
>   following:
>
> - Questions
> - Non-deleted only
> - Answers - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
> - Non-deleted AND
> - Score > 0 AND
> - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
> - In the top 3 answers OR
> - Is the Accepted Answer OR
> - Score at least 5 OR
> - Has at least 20% of the total vote count
>
> (Note on closed questions: we originally were excluding closed
>   questions, too, but it seemed to cause more harm than good: the ones
>   that never should have been here almost all get closed before
>   attracting many views, so including them very rarely matters. But the
>   ones that are closed with a ton of views almost all were permissible
>   back in the day, so having the score plummet when the rules evolve
>   seemed more harm than the alternative, since the impact is so small
>   there.)

Source [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)

#### Why should I care?

It tells you how helpful your contributions are to other users. Whether you care about that is up to you.